# how do i use a ruby if statement in a js.erb file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need to do something like shown below; add a jquery effect depending on the value of an instance object in rails

```
("$('#cart').show(2000);") if @cart.total_items ==1
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<% if @cart.total_items ==1 %>
  $('#cart').show(2000);
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

@xdazz answer is right , but i used to use the conditional statements as follows

```
var mycount = <%= @cart.total_items %>

if (mycount == 1){
$("#cart").show(2000)
}
```

The reason i use mostly `conditional statements` in javascript (in js.erb file) is because this seems easy to handle